# OpenCV holds the memory longer than it is needed

Tags: opencv

I have a program that does something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cv::Mat mats[10];
        for (auto & m : mats) {
            m = cv::Mat::zeros(5000, 5000, CV_8U);
            // use the mats ...
        }
    }

    getchar(); // at this point, process holds hundreds of megabytes of memory
}
```

After this code block ends, the `Mat`s are out of scope and there are definitely no other references to the data, the process somehow still takes hundreds of megabytes of RAM. If I do this Instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cv::Mat mats[10];
        for (auto & m : mats) {
            m.data = new uchar[5000 * 5000];
            // use the memory ...
            memset(m.data, i, 5000 * 5000);
        }
        for (auto & m : mats) {
            delete m.data;
        }
    }

    getchar(); // at this point, process holds almost zero memory
}
```

the process takes almost zero memory after this code.
I am guessing OpenCV has some internal memory management where it doesn't free the memory for potential future use.
That's a problem for me because I need this memory for other things after this code run. This process serves as a server so it stays up indefinitely. Is there a way to force OpenCV to free this memory?

I am using OpenCV 4.3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: please post a minimal working example

Comment: What’s the memory footprint if you manually `release` the mats after you don’t need them?

Comment: Maybe this can help. [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/). After using opencv Mat class use release.

Comment: @eldesgraciado Has no effect

Comment: @Miki added a minimal working example